# Group list of objects with the same id/name using java stream

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have a List of objects of the class Student like List. Student class has a sorted map of Date & object of another class Score
See below:

```
class Student{
    String name;
    SortedMap<LocalDate, Score> semScore = new TreeMap()<>; 
}
```

```
class Score{
   int score;
   String grade;
}
```

How can I aggregate the list of students to merge all the sorted maps to a single map group by student name.
For e.g

```
Score score = new Score(90, "A");
SortedMap<LocalDate, Score> sMap = new TreeMap<>();
sMap.put(LocalDate.now(), score);

Student s = new Student("Bob", sMap);

So multiple records are in the list for a Student with a given name with one map of score.
I need to aggregate all the scores into the same student object like group by name.

How can we do it using java streams?

Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to merge them the `Collectors#toMap`comprises of a merge function:

```
Map<String, Student> mergedStudents = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getName, Function.identity(), (s1, s2) -> {
  SortedMap<LocalDate, Score> semScore = new TreeMap<>(s1.getSemScore());
  semScore.putAll(s2.getSemScore());
  return new Student(s1.getName(), semScore);
}));
```

Comment: Can it be possible to modify the existing one and return in merge function?

Comment: Yes. Simply add the s2.semScore to s1 and return s1.